# Predict Class names Using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to predict exact class name but sklearn is giving me an array when I use these Code

```
    predicted_labels = model_knn.predict(testing_set)
    predicted_labels
```

but I get an Array like these

```
array([ 0,  8,  6,  0,  0,  7,  0, 13,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  1, 15,  1,  1,
       11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

when I try to use

```
    print(labelencoder.inverse_transform(predicted_labels))
```

I get these error

```
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: [ 1  6  7  8 11 13 14 15]
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to encode the labels?

Comment: # Encode Labels
    labelencoder = LabelEncoder()          
    labelencoder.fit(labels)
    print(len(labelencoder.classes_), "classes:", ", 
    ".join(list(labelencoder.classes_)))
    classes_num = labelencoder.transform(labels)

Comment: Is the KNN model predicting based on the transformed output from the label encoder? If not, the inverse transform won't work.

Comment: You have `classes_num = labelencoder.transform(...)` but the variable naming is confusing I think you meant `classes_num = labelencoder.classes_` because transform will change all data passed into it to match the classes created when fitting on the data.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better understanding your issue and help.

Comment: What did you expect to get as output?